# A curve is a circle or a line

Tags: plane-curves

Let $\gamma(t):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuous curve in the plane such that for every $t_1,t_2\in\mathbb{R}$ the euclidean distance $d(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2))$ depends only on $|t_1-t_2|$. Must the curve be a circle or a line?

I believe the answer is affirmative and tried to find a Möbius transformation that maps the curve to a generalized circle, or to show that the cross-ratio $[\gamma(0),\gamma(1),\gamma(2),\gamma(t)]$ (for arbitrary $t$) is a real number, but couldn't figure it out. Appreciate any advice!

Comment: When you say "the euclidean distance $d(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2))$ depends only on $|t_1-t_2|$", do you mean that $d(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2))=|t_1-t_2|$? Or if not, is there any details on the dependence?

Comment: @NazimJ I understood it as a function of the quantity $|t_1-t_2|$ and that quantity alone, which is making m scratch my head ad Infinitum.

Comment: This appears as a bonus problem in Ted Shifrin’s differential geometry text.

Comment: @amd It seems that [in that text](http://math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180619110300/http://math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf)), there is an additional assumption that the curve is smooth. The text also mentions that it is "a special case of a recent American Mathematical Monthly problem".

Comment: No smoothness is needed, although my original solution used some derivatives to characterize the curve as having constant curvature. The fact that it appears in the first section of my text suggests that there is, indeed, a far more elementary solution.

Comment: I don't think your approach(es) are likely to work. You have to localize things to see the underlying geometry, so take a closed interval in $\Bbb R$ (which is how I originally posed the problem, anyhow) and chop it into small pieces of equal length.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Unless you specify what you mean by *"depends only on $|t_1 - t_2|$"* I'd say that the problem is false. For instance, if $\| \gamma (t_1) - \gamma (t_2) \| = 0$ then the curve reduces to a single point. This is an axtreme, but valid case of dependancy on $|t_1 - t_2|$. To be more precise: if $\| \gamma (t_1) - \gamma (t_2) \| = f(|t_1 - t_2|)$, what conditions should be imposed upon $f$ (in particular: regularity conditions)?

Comment: @AlexM. a single point is a circle (of radius $0$).

Answer (score 2):

The core of this problem is a simple geometry problem.  Let $A=\gamma (t_0), B=\gamma (t_0+t), C=\gamma (t_0+2t), D=\gamma (t_0+3t)$. We have the following distance equalities: $|A-B|=|B-C|=|C-D|$ and $|A-C|=|B-D|$.  Triangle $A-B-C$ is thus congruent to triangle $B-C-D$.  If points $A, B, C etc.$ are collinear then the curve will turn out to be a line, because $t_0$, and $t$ are arbitrary.  Otherwise Let $L_1$ be the line through point $B$ which bisects angle $A-B-C$ let $L_2$ be the line through point $C$ which bisects angle $B-C-D$, and  point $G$ be the intersection of $L_1$, and $L_2$.  Triangle $B-G-C$ is an isosceles triangle, because angle $G-B-C$ equals angle $G-C-B$. At this point distance $|B-G|=|C-G|$.  Wrapping things up, this construction works for any $t_0$, and the triangles involved are always congruent, so point $G$ is distance $|B-G|$ from every point on the curve.

Comment: What if $A=(0, 0)$, $B=(1, 1)$, $C=(2, 0)$, $D=(3, 1)$ ? Then $L_1, L_2$ do not intersect.

Comment: @MartinR You are right, but this cannot happen for a continuous curve.  Imagine starting the points $A, B, C$ construction at $t_1=t_0 $ and slide $t_1$ along to $t_0+t$.  The point where line segment $A-C$ jumps from one side of the curve to the other would be a discontinuity.  If they are on the same side then the angle between $L_1, L_2$ is twice angle $B-A-C$.

Comment: Well, that is the challenge of this problem (in my opinion): To prove rigorously what *seems* obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the image of $\gamma$ contains three noncollinear points $A_k=\gamma(a_k) (k=1,2,3)$.

Let $s\in{\mathbb R}$. If we put $\eta_s(t)=\gamma(s+t)$, then we have $d(\eta_s(t_1),\eta_s(t_2))=d(\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2))$ for any $t_1,t_2$. By a well-known exercise, there is a isometry of $\mathbb R^2$ sending each $\gamma(t)$ to the corresponding $\eta_s(t)$. This isometry is in fact unique because  an isometry is uniquely determined by its values on the three points $A_1,A_2,A_3$.

We shall denote this unique isometry by $R_s$ ; the fundamental equation is then

$$
\gamma(x+t)=R_t(\gamma(x)) \tag{1}
$$

Evaulating $\gamma(x+t_1+t_2)$ in two ways using (1), we deduce

$$
R_{t_1+t_2}=R_{t_1} \circ R_{t_2} \tag{2}
$$

If $R_1$ is a rotation with center $W$ and angle $\theta$, it is easy
to see that $R_t$ is the rotation with center $W$ and angle $t\theta$ (do it first for rational $t$ by algebra, then extend to all of $\mathbb R$ using the continuity of $\gamma$). It follows then from (1) that the image of $\gamma$ is a circle centered at $W$.

If $R_1$ is a translation with vector $v$, it is easy
to see that $R_t$ is the translation with vector $tv$ (do it first for rational $t$ by algebra, then extend to all of $\mathbb R$ using the continuity of $\gamma$). It follows then from (1) that the image of $\gamma$ is a line directed by $v$.

APPENDIX: The well-known exercise.

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a set, and let $\eta,\gamma$ be two maps
$\eta : X \to {\mathbb R}^a, \gamma : X \to {\mathbb R}^b$ be two that are "isometric", i.e. we have $d(\eta(x),\eta(x'))=d(\gamma(x),\gamma(x'))$ for any $x,x'\in X$.
 Then there is an isometry $i$ (from an affine subspace of ${\mathbb R}^a$ to an affine subspace of ${\mathbb R}^b$  sending $\gamma$ to $\eta$, i.e. $i(\gamma(x))=\eta(x)$ for any $x\in X$.

**Proof :**  We may assume that $X$ is nonempty. Let $x_0 \in X$. Composing $\gamma$ and $\eta$ on the left with translations, we can assume that $\gamma(x_0)=\eta(x_0)=0$, which reduces the initial "affine" problem to a purely "vectorial" one.

The advantage of this reduction is that all this distance stuff may be reformulated in terms of the scalar product (using the formula $\langle u,v\rangle=\frac{d(u,0)^2+d(v,0)^2-d(u,v)^2}{2}$) : we now have $(*) : \langle\eta(x),\eta(x')\rangle=\langle\gamma(x),\gamma(x')\rangle$ for any $x,x'\in X$.

Decreasing $a$ and $b$ if necessary, we may assume that $\gamma(X)$ spans all of ${\mathbb R}^a$ and $\eta(X)$ spans all of ${\mathbb R}^b$.

There is a $X_0 \subseteq X$ with cardinality $a$, such that $\gamma(X_0)$ is a basis of ${\mathbb R}^a$. Write $X_0=\lbrace x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_a \rbrace$, and put $g_k=\gamma(x_k) (0\leq k \leq a)$, so that for example $g_0=0$.

Because of (*), the unique linear map $i$ sending $g_k$ to $\eta(x_k)$ is in fact an isometry. Finally, for any $x\in X$ the two vectors $i(\gamma(x))$ and $\eta(x)$ are the same, because they have the same coordinates in the system defined by $(\eta(x_1),\ldots,\eta(x_k))$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance: Which *“well-known convex extension exercise”* are you talking of? Some hint or link would be appreciated.

Comment: @MartinR Unfortunately I can't think of any reference off the top of my head, but I am certain it is well-known. I'll add an explanation to my answer when I have the time, in the meantime perhaps someone with a better memory than me can supply a reference

Comment: It would already help if you quote what exactly you are using: what are the conditions and what is the conclusion.

Comment: @MartinR the full proof has now been added.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

(Another) geometric approach to solve it:

Let $P_n = \gamma(t_0 + n \cdot t)$. Then, it can shown (*) that $P_{-2}P_{2}P_{1}P_{-1}$ is an isosceles trapezoid or that they are collinear. Therefore, if 3 points are collinear, all of them are so. Otherwise, all of them belong to the circumference defined by three points, since the fourth point always completes an isosceles trapezoid, which is a cyclic quadrilateral.

The proof of (*) goes as follows: the two legs of $P_{-2}P_{2}P_{1}P_{-1}$ are equal, and the two diagonals too. If we fix the base $P_{-2}P_{2}$, there are only two alternatives for the other two vertices. They are either on the line $P_{-2}P_{2}$ (getting collinear points), on the same half-plane (thus getting an isosceles trapezoid), or on a different half-plane. The latter is actually impossible: it implies that $P_0$ is in the intersection of $P_{-2}P_{2}$ and $P_{-1}P_{1}$, and we can use the triangular inequality on $\triangle P_0P_1P_2$ to derive the contradiction $f(|2t|) < f(|2t|)$:

$f(|2t|) = d(P_0, P_2) < d(P_0, P_1) + d(P_1, P_2) = d(P_{-1}, P_0) + d(P_0, P_1) = d(P_{-1}, P_1) = f(|2t|)$.

Comment: I must admit that the conclusion $d(P_0, P_2) > d(P_{-1}, P_1)$ is not obvious to me. Can you elaborate on that part?

Comment: I was wrong, rather than "greater than" was "less than", thank you for pointing it out. I added a small proof. Maybe this is more intuitive: both P_{-1} and P_{1} lie on the medians of, respectively P_{-2}, P_0, and P_0, P_2, and the distance between those medians is exactly d(P_0, P_2). Thus, the distances are equal only if they form a trapezoid (that is, with parallel bases).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\overline{x}=\overline{x}(t)=(f(t),g(t))$, $t\in\textbf{R}$ is a plane curve, such that for every $t_1,t\in \textbf{R}$ we have
$$
|\overline{x}(t_1)-\overline{x}(t)|=h\left(t_1-t\right).\tag 1
$$

If we assume that $h(t)$ is such that 
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(t)}{t}=l<\infty,
$$
then $\overline{x}(t)$ is differentiatable and $\overline{x}(t)$ is circle or line.

PROOF.
We can write
$$
|\overline{x}(t)-\overline{x}(t_1)|=h(t-t_1)\Rightarrow \left|\frac{\overline{x}(t)-\overline{x}(t_1)}{t-t_1}\right|=
$$
$$
=\sqrt{\left(\frac{f(t)-f(t_1)}{t-t_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{g(t)-g(t_1)}{t-t_1}\right)^2}=\frac{h(t-t_1)}{t-t_1}.\tag 2
$$
Hence taking the limit $t \rightarrow t_1$ in both sides of $(2)$ we get
$$
\sqrt{f'(t_1)^2+g'(t_1)^2}=l=constant\textrm{, for all }t_1\in D\subseteq \textbf{R}.
$$
Hence for the lenght $s=s(t)$ of the curve $\overline{x}(t)$, we have
$$
s=lt+c_1.
$$
Assumming the polar coordinates $r=r(\theta)$, we get (the length of a curve is an invriant) 
$$
\dot{s}^2=\left(\frac{ds}{d\theta}\right)^2=c^2=r(\theta)^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2\tag 3
$$ 
Hence solving the DE $(3)$, we get 
$$
r(\theta)=c\frac{\tan(\theta\pm C_1)}{\sqrt{1+\tan(\theta\pm C_1)^2}},
$$
which are circles and lines, since
$$
\frac{\tan(\theta\pm C_1)}{\sqrt{1+\tan(\theta\pm C_1)^2}}=\frac{\left|\cos(\theta\pm C_1)\right|\tan(\theta\pm C_1)}{\sqrt{\cos(\theta\pm C_1)^2+\sin(\theta\pm C_1)^2}}
$$
and thus
$$
r(\theta)=c\left|\cos(\theta\pm C_1)\right|\tan(\theta\pm C_1)
$$

NOTE. In case $y=f(t)$ i.e. the curve $\overline{x}(t)=(t,f(t))$ is a function, then condition $(2)$ becomes 
$$
\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2}=l
$$
and $y=f(t)$ is a line.